# Inputting Non ASCII characters to scanf("%s")

Tags: c, format, scanf, buffer-overflow

Is there a way one can issue non ascii hex characters to a scanf that uses `%s` ? I'm trying to insert hexadecimal chars like `\x08\xDE\xAD` and so on (to demonstrate buffer overflow).

The input is not to a command line parameter, but to a scanf inside the program.

Comment: Then why not `fprintf("\0xDE")` to the standard input of your program?

Comment: If you can type those characters on your keyboard, that should work. Otherwise, a redirect, `./a.out < file_with_shellcode`?

Comment: My first edit didnt go through. What you're saying will work if the input was a command line argument. This however is not a command line argument. And the characters I want to print are not Printable.

Comment: What do you mean by "hexadecimal characters"? If by `\x08` you mean the ASCII backspace character, hexadecimal is just a human-readable way to represent it; the character itself is just a (non-printable) character. And how does reading non-printable characters with `scanf` demonstrate buffer overflow? A long sequence of printable characters would do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to feed arbitrary data on stdin (since you read with `scanf`).

You can use the shell to create the data and pipe it into your program, e.g.

```
printf '\x08\xDE\xAD' | yourprogram
```

Note that this will only work as long as there are no white-space characters to be fed (because `scanf` with a `%s` format stops at white-space).

Comment: If you're on Windows and don't have the `printf` command, make a file and redirect `stdin` to it: `yourprogram < deadfile`

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'to a `scanf()`', presumably there is other data than just this to be supplied.  Would it work to have a program, perhaps a Perl or Python script, generate the data and write the non-ASCII characters to the standard input of your program?  If you need standard input to appear like a terminal, then you should investigate [`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/) which handles that for you.  This is a common way of dealing with the problem.